# Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError --> No module named 'sql' when running Python

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda 3 to run Python but unable to run certain Python code.

Below is the first cell of the Python code and the first 2 rows of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBFBU.jpg)

Below is the remaining error message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dclzq.jpg)

Summary of the error message (1st and last row): ModuleNotFoundError . . . No module named 'sql'

What am I missing here? I can run some simpler Python code but unable to run more complex ones.

I think the main difference between the 2 Python scripts is this: %load_ext sql This particular line of script is not in the simpler Python code.

PS Database is Oracle

Comment: It seems you need SQL.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks. Please refer to my own answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My colleague has just resolved this issue for me.

I actually commented out this bit --> `%load_ext sql` and it ran but then we are not sure what it would affect and hence we resolved it properly.

Basically, open up the Anaconda Prompt and run `pip install ipython-sql`  <-- this would install this module/thing required.

If you also come across issue related to `cx_oracle`.  In the same command prompt and run `pip install cx_oracle`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the module with "pip install", not "conda install". Then activate the conda venv.